# How to navigate from one storyboard to another TabBarController?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I'm trying to create an onboarding page for my Application which view is like this :

[image: Onboarding.storyboard]

The Not Now Button supposed to navigate from this Onboarding Storyboard to ForYou Storyboard which have a storyboard that embed in navigation controller and tab bar controller.

[image: ForYou.storyboard]

Based on my research, i can use this line of code to make it happened

```
let barViewControllers = UIStoryboardSegue.init(identifier: "ForYou", source: OnboardingMasterViewController(), destination: ForYouViewController()) as! UITabBarController
let nav = barViewControllers.viewControllers![0] as! UINavigationController
let destinationViewController = nav.topViewController as! ForYouViewController
```

It build successfully but when i run it on simulator, the apps crash and show this line of error that i never see or learn before. The error is Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

[image: Error Message]

I tried to look to google but either i used a wrong keyword or my lack of understanding, i still can't solved this error. Hope one of you can give me a guidance in finding the solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you have already given an identifier to the Segue that I can see on the `Onboarding` Storyboard to `ForYou` Storyboard.

If not, click on that Segue in your storyboard and give its identifier.

Now, on the `Not Now` button's action you can do the following instead of the code that you have

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "your-segue-identifier", sender: nil)
```

OR

You can directly connect the Segue in the storyboard from your `Not Now` button to `ForYou` storyboard, that way you won't need to write any code to achieve this.